# How to get admob ad without using xml

Tags: java, android, admob

I cannot get admob ads to show up on my game it just ends up crashing it. I can't see ads with test ads or real ones. I have even tried it on real phone instead of emulator. I have put it under dependencies in my gradle file but I am not sure what to put under manifests if anything at all. I completed the game and it is ready to publish to playstore. But I am unable to add admob banner to my game. admob tutorials i searched all ended up for .xml layout but my setContentView(); executes the java class. Please help me solve the problem.

```js
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // adview code
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        // ads parameter
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        adView.setLayoutParams(params1);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // layout list
        layout.addView(adView);
        layout.addView(adView);

        setContentView(layout);

        // ads request
        AdRequest request=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        adView.loadAd(request);



        //turn title off
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //set to full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));




// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        });
    }
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Call displayInterstitial() function
        displayInterstitial();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `ends up crashing it` have you checked the exception and a stacktrace?

Comment: It launches fine but it immediately says the game has stopped working when it opens.

Comment: `have you checked the exception and a stacktrace`?

Comment: no I don't know how to do that but it says MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API in the console

Comment: then you should find out, how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)